# Unexplained space in flexbox in DIV with CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my code for a template I made (sections quoted and CSS are only for the flexbox):

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;

}
.flex-left {
    width: 75%;    
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex-right {
background-color: red;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.flex-left1 {
width: 50%;
}

.flex-left1 img {
width: 330px;
}

.flex-right1 {
width: 90%;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.av2 {
margin: 70px;
margin-right: 130px;
width: 830px;
border: 2px solid;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="av2">
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left">
       2011 SWIFT BOLERO 2.3TD
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
       £19,495
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left1">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RqgOLq7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right1">
    

Unregistered Swift Bolero 714 SB - Front Lounge Seating Transformable Into Double Bed, O/S Kitchen, Opposite Single Beds, Rear Transverse Bathroom.

This vehicle has Vogue Pack including twin view colour reversing camera allowing use en-route, cab air conditioning, cruise control, status 570 TV aerial. Winter Pack including fresh and waste water tank heaters, underfloor waste pipe insulation, fridge vent covers.

The Bolero range is strong, resilient and aerodynamic yet still simply modern and elegant in its appearance. The Bolero range sports the Duvalay Duvalite mattress on all the fixed beds giving you the ultimate night?s sleep after those long days touring the world. The Swift Command system allows you to remotely control your habitation functions from your smartphone or tablet through the App.
SN 26

    </div>
</div>
</article>

<article class="av2">
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left">
       2011 SWIFT BOLERO 2.3TD
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
       £19,495
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left1">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RqgOLq7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right1">
    

Unregistered Swift Bolero 714 SB - Front Lounge Seating Transformable Into Double Bed, O/S Kitchen, Opposite Single Beds, Rear Transverse Bathroom.

This vehicle has Vogue Pack including twin view colour reversing camera allowing use en-route, cab air conditioning, cruise control, status 570 TV aerial. Winter Pack including fresh and waste water tank heaters, underfloor waste pipe insulation, fridge vent covers.

The Bolero range is strong, resilient and aerodynamic yet still simply modern and elegant in its appearance. The Bolero range sports the Duvalay Duvalite mattress on all the fixed beds giving you the ultimate night?s sleep after those long days touring the world. The Swift Command system allows you to remotely control your habitation functions from your smartphone or tablet through the App.
SN 26

    </div>
</div>
</article>
```

This is the area causing the problem:

```
<div class="flex-left">
       2011 SWIFT BOLERO 2.3TD
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
       £19,495
    </div>
```

In the above example, there's whitespace between flex-left and flex-right; how can I make it look like there's no space with the DIV?

Also, for flex right, if I make .ax2 longer (i.e. 1050px) I can't get the flex to go to the end of the DIV and the text when I try text-align: right doesn't go quite where I want it.

What changes should I make to ensure this works properly?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to remove the 5px left margin from `flex-right`:

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;

}
.flex-left {
    width: 75%;    
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex-right {
background-color: red;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: right;
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
}

.flex-left1 {
width: 50%;
}

.flex-left1 img {
width: 330px;
}

.flex-right1 {
width: 90%;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.av2 {
margin: 70px;
margin-right: 130px;
width: 830px;
border: 2px solid;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="av2">
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left">
       2011 SWIFT BOLERO 2.3TD
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
       £19,495
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left1">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RqgOLq7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right1">
    

Unregistered Swift Bolero 714 SB - Front Lounge Seating Transformable Into Double Bed, O/S Kitchen, Opposite Single Beds, Rear Transverse Bathroom.

This vehicle has Vogue Pack including twin view colour reversing camera allowing use en-route, cab air conditioning, cruise control, status 570 TV aerial. Winter Pack including fresh and waste water tank heaters, underfloor waste pipe insulation, fridge vent covers.

The Bolero range is strong, resilient and aerodynamic yet still simply modern and elegant in its appearance. The Bolero range sports the Duvalay Duvalite mattress on all the fixed beds giving you the ultimate night?s sleep after those long days touring the world. The Swift Command system allows you to remotely control your habitation functions from your smartphone or tablet through the App.
SN 26

    </div>
</div>
</article>

<article class="av2">
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left">
       2011 SWIFT BOLERO 2.3TD
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
       £19,495
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left1">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RqgOLq7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right1">
    

Unregistered Swift Bolero 714 SB - Front Lounge Seating Transformable Into Double Bed, O/S Kitchen, Opposite Single Beds, Rear Transverse Bathroom.

This vehicle has Vogue Pack including twin view colour reversing camera allowing use en-route, cab air conditioning, cruise control, status 570 TV aerial. Winter Pack including fresh and waste water tank heaters, underfloor waste pipe insulation, fridge vent covers.

The Bolero range is strong, resilient and aerodynamic yet still simply modern and elegant in its appearance. The Bolero range sports the Duvalay Duvalite mattress on all the fixed beds giving you the ultimate night?s sleep after those long days touring the world. The Swift Command system allows you to remotely control your habitation functions from your smartphone or tablet through the App.
SN 26

    </div>
</div>
</article>
```

I commented out that line in your CSS.